# How to estimate time / difficulty to brute force scrypt (or similar) hash at various short fixed lengh outputs?

Tags: hash, brute-force-attack, scrypt

My particular use case is a hash function that:

1. Is slow / computationally expensive. It would take a pretty long time, or be infeasible to guess the input, if the hash output and the algorithm are provided.
2. Has a pretty short output. The shorter, the better, want a trade-off between difficulty and size

I am a cryptography hobbyist (so not too knowledgeable yet), and want to use this for a small experiment. I am aware of the scrypt algorithm which is intentionally slowed and bloated (resource wise) to make brute forcing more difficult. I found [this online tool](https://www.browserling.com/tools/scrypt) where it outputs the hash with a given input, optional salt, output length, and options for CPU difficulty, memory difficulty, and parallelization difficulty adjustment.

I want to determine the relationship between making something infeasible to brute force while reducing the output size the most. Since scrypt seems to handle my use case I am thinking might use this function, but I want to know how to use it effectively, and how to determine that I'm doing so.

I think that increasing the memory difficulty a certain amount can prevent ASICs as well as current GPUs from attempting these calculations, limiting to only CPUs. I think that's an effective way to achieve my use case. What is this difficulty level, or how would I determine it?

Also, given that the output will be small, I'm looking to reduce collision resistance. I think that using a random number salt would achieve this. Is there some kind of limit on the upper bound for the salt value, or something that relates the salt space (I don't know the terminology) to the collision resistance? Hopefully my mental model of this checks out, let me know if not, as I'm pretty new to some of this.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. Collision resistance has nothing to do with password hashing. The first and second pre-images are important. Half of the question is experimental and you did not share what you tried on your target platform. Why do you use Scrypt, not the Argon2, and why do you want to restrict the output size less than 128-bit?

Comment: It is my understanding that by achieving collision resistance, first and second pre-image resistance is also imlpied. I agree that this question is largely experimental, I am hoping to gain understanding in a new area. I initially thought of crc32 since it has 8 byte output, but it is very weak and fast to guess. I turned to scrypt because I recognize it from cryptocurrency space and get its use case. Thanks for the suggestion of Argon2. I can read more about it - what drives your suggestion?

Comment: Nope. MD5 and SHA-1 are not collision-resistant, however, they have first and second. If it is a new project then use Argon2. CRC has no place in password hashing.

Comment: Good points, I agree that the preimage resistance is what's important here, and that CRC is an awful choice. I only looked to it because of the small output. I'm just learning about how these newer functions are parameterized in the ways I'm looking for. I think my Qs are the same with Argon2. I want to know how I can evaluate the effectiveness of my parameters. I assume that with short outputs, I might have to increase some of these difficulty parameters more than with a long output. How can I estimate these?

Comment: https://www.password-hashing.net/argon2-specs.pdf